# Understanding "Et comme si le temps eût pu s’arrêter avec moi"

Tags: conditionnel, imparfait

The question is on this beautiful passage from chapter 7 of La porte étroite by André Gide and particularly the highlighted words.

> Elle était au fond du jardin. Je m’acheminai vers ce rond-point, étroitement entouré de buissons, à cette époque de l’année tout en fleurs, lilas, sorbiers, cytises, weigelias ; pour ne point l’apercevoir de trop loin, ou pour qu’elle ne me vît pas venir, je suivis, de l’autre côté du jardin, l’allée sombre où l’air était frais sous les branches. J’avançais lentement ; le ciel était comme ma joie, chaud, brillant, délicatement pur. Sans doute elle m’attendait venir par l’autre allée ; je fus près d’elle, derrière elle, sans qu’elle m’eût entendu approcher ; je m’arrêtai… Et comme si le temps **eût pu** s’arrêter avec moi : voici l’instant, pensai-je, l’instant le plus délicieux peut-être, quand il précéderait le bonheur même, et que le bonheur même ne vaudra pas…

**QUESTION**

1. *eût pu* is conditionnel passé deuxième forme?  (I am guessing so because time stopping is counterfactual.)
2. If yes to 1, then we can replace it with *avait pu*?
3. If yes to both 1 and 2, why was it better to use *eût pu*?
4. Please feel free to explain in general terms when and why, in a counterfactual about the past, conditionnel passé deuxième forme may be preferable to plus-que-parfait (in the *si* clause) or conditionnel passé première forme (outside the *si* clause).

**BACKGROUND**

I realize I asked a similar question in this [earlier post](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24192/the-use-of-the-conditional-vs-the-subjunctive-for-similar-looking-purposes-in-g).  But I feel that each type of context in which a choice is made between conditionnel passé deuxième forme and première forme (or plus-que-parfait) should deserve a separate question.

Besides, Teleporting Goat, who kindly answered the earlier question, said there that it was hard to tell which choice sounded better.  Perhaps, this different context will bring out some more concrete criteria?

Comment: Same thing - it is hard for me to tell which tense would be "better". Those "u" sounds sound a bit precious to me, but I don't know a precise grammatical rule recommending the use of one or another, and they sound both fine - I mean, you might need to be consistent in your choice throughout, but I can't fault one or the other. Probably boils down to style again.

Comment: @Frank. The trouble is that Gide will go back and forth, apparently preferring one to the other for any given occasion. StéphaneGimenez (in comments to the other question) said something about timing making a difference, which I couldn't follow. Anyway if anyone has the answer, no one has *given* it. So I think I should accept T.G. and, now, your saying that there is no discernible difference. Thanks.

Comment: this is again quite subtle, so even French people might have trouble finding a rationale for one or the other (I do), so we punt and say it's "style". By the way, that style of Gide in the passage above doesn't quite work for me. I find it _heavy_ and convoluted :-)

Comment: I have an issue with _elle m’attendait venir par l’autre allée_ though. It feels broken to me, I was expecting something between _m’attendait_ et _venir_.

Comment: @Frank. Indeed, my dictionary lists *s'attendre à*.  As for heaviness, I myself normally prefer spare writing. The primary beauty of the passage is in how it relates to the whole story, which is a prolonged expectation of a happiness that was never to be, at one level. Of course, you couldn't get that just from this passage.

Comment: I am actually not sure _what_ is missing between _attendait_ and _venir_. I would have naturally said: _sans doute s'attendait-elle a ce que je vienne par l’autre allée_ or something like that (please ignore questions of style, and let's compare to Gide's style :-). Usually, it's _s'attendre à qqch_, where _s'_ refers back to the subject of attendre - but here _m'_ refers to the object. Curious.

Comment: @Frank. Oh yes, I was totally wrong to appeal to *s'attendre à*. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. yes, it's conditionel 'second form'. That form is used almost exclusively in literature.
2. You could replace it by 'aurait pu' which is the conditionel 'first form'. 'avait pu' has a slightly different meaning, almost as if there was an opportunity for time to stop, but somehow it didn't happen. With the conditionel tense, the author wants to convey that time stopping can only be dreamt of and not actually something that could happen.
3. as above, in literature the second form gives a much more 'stylish' tone to the sentence, and reads better than the first form. The meaning is the same.
4. As above.

Comment: Thank you. I am somewhat confused by your characterizing the difference as one of meaning in 2, but in 3 as one of only style and tone (while the meaning remains "the same"). Would it be fair if I understood: (a) One can either always use the first form or mix the two forms (as in literature), and that's a matter of style. (b) But if you choose to mix the two forms then the second form is reserved for impossibilities and near impossibilities, while the first form is for what is merely not the case. Thus, a difference in meaning guides the choice.

Comment: @Catomic - not to contest Rémy's interpretation in 2., but IMHO it is again somewhat objective, rather than a grammatical rule. Whether you use "aurait pu" or "avait pu", there is anyway "comme si" at the beginning of the phrase, and that "comme si" takes over and brings in the notion of possibility rather than actuality.

Comment: @Catomic - I think the majority of the questions you ask lately are not decidable with explicit rules, but are more opinion or style based. I would be very careful to not try to find rules when IMHO there might not be any. Of course, it is interesting to see how different people react to these phrases. But there is going to be many point of views, none of them more valid than the others :-)

Comment: @Frank. Those different reactions of people are very helpful to someone like me just starting to learn the language and with no reaction of his own (other than to be puzzled). But duly noting your advice against expecting bright line rules.

Comment: @Frank. I think Rémy Joandel would agree with your first comment. He would simply make the further point that conditionnel passé deuxième forme is for even remoter (more unlikely, sometimes impossible) counterfactuals, while the first form (plus-que-parfait within *si*) is for less remote--that is, if one made the stylistic choice to take advantage of both alternatives

Comment: @Catomic - maybe, and I could understand that rationale, but I couldn't vouch for it truly being a rule of the French language.

Comment: @Catomic - just to clarify - aurait pu (first form) would have the same meaning as 'eut pu' , and the choice between the 2 is a matter of style. 'avait pu' has a slightly different meaning. but as Franck said, this is my interpretation as a native speaker, i wouldn't pretend to be able to pull a definite rule for this!

Comment: From the same book: 'N’y a-t-il rien à quoi nous *puissions* nous occuper ensemble ?' This could have been *pourrions*? If yes, it seems to throw out the window the idea of the subjunctive being *more unlikely or even impossible* than conditional. @Frank

Comment: Hmmm - indeed - _pourrions_ sounds probable to me...

Comment: For this kind of question, if you are up to it, I would recommend consulting the Grevisse (http://www.lebonusage.com/). This should have all the answers you are looking and then some, definitely a good investment in my opinion.

Comment: I'm quoting from the Grevisse I have: "le subjonctif est le mode des phrases injonctives et des phrases optatives, pour les personnes manquant à l'impératif. Il est fréquent aussi pour les verbes qui sont des prédicats de proposition, et non des phrases: il indique alors que le locuteur ne s'engage pas sur la réalité du fait."

Comment: Another quote: "Dans un récit au passé, les faits futurs sont ordinairement au conditionnel. Mais, si le récit est au présent historique, ils sont souvent au temps futur."

Comment: And some examples for the conditional: "Elle n'aurait pas été plutôt arrivée qu'elle s'en serait aperçue (Proust)" - all from the Grevisse - I think it is the book you want :-)