# Why is this subjunctive past perfect used here?

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif, conditionnel

> Une femme nous parait-elle aimable ? Nous la prenons pour cette moitié avec laquelle nous n'**eussions fait** qu'un ​tout. Le cœur dit la voila, c'est elle. mais a l’épreuve hélas. Trop souvent ce ne l'est point.

I don't understand why this form is used here.

Comment: [This question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/24192/1893) is closely related; does it answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

Ce n'est pas un subjonctif, mais un

- conditionnel passé 2ème forme.

voir ici : https://commentconjuguer.com/verbe/faire

Mais c'est aussi désuet que l'imparfait du subjonctif.

---

This is not the subjunctive, but the past conditional second form.

See link above.

This is as old-fashioned as subjunctive past perfect.

Comment: What is thhe difference bbetween this form and aurion fait form? and what does thhe sentence mean?

Comment: @user21669 Exact same meaning as "aurions fait" for me, just more old-fashioned (XIXth century style). The whole sentence is about how sometimes we think we've found our moitié (half=soul-mate), but often it's not the case.